# Automatically mock modules in Mocha JS (ala Jest)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, reactjs, jestjs

I've been enjoying Jest's [automatic mocks](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/automatic-mocking.html#content) for testing my ReactJS components. But Jest is a very new testing tool, and it's missing many essential features, e.g. [the ability to run tests in a browser](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jestjs/Ell1g4hSltg). It's also unclear whether it's under active development.

Is it possible to get Jest's mock-by-default behavior using Mocha JS? To be clear, what I would like is that every `require` statement returns a mock of the underlying module, unless I specifically say not to mock that module.

Comment: I [tried](https://github.com/danvk/stub-require) to get this working, but ultimately realized that it was surprisingly tricky, particularly for React Components which need to have `instanceof ReactDescriptor` evaluate to `true`. I wound up stubbing out React Components [in a prepreprocessor](https://github.com/hammerlab/cycledash/blob/master/__tests__/js/preprocessor.js) to get this working with Mocha. I'm quite happy with the results.

Comment: Looks like a nice idea. Your link to the preprocessor was broken, so here is the [correct link](https://github.com/hammerlab/cycledash/blob/master/tests/js/preprocessor.js). I found the [jsx-stub-transformer.js](https://github.com/hammerlab/cycledash/blob/master/tests/js/jsx-stub-transformer.js) file informative too.